# Auto populate field in create mutation with Velocity resolver in AppSync Apmplify

Tags: graphql, aws-amplify, velocity, aws-appsync, aws-appsync-resolver

In my AWS amplify app, I have 3 dynamodb tables. *User*, *Post* and *Comment*. *Post* belongs to a *User*. *Commnet* belongs to a *Post*. With velocity resolvers, in `createComment` mutation, I want to auto populate the `postCommentsId` (foreign key) field of *Comments* table by first querying the *Post* table with `Post.owner` (I have the ID of the logged in user - `$ctx.identity.username`) to get the current user's `Post.id` (Assuming *User* only has one *Post*). I want to create a resolver as a part of a pipeline and slot it in.

If I extend an existing resolver (say *preDataLoad*) from the *Comment* stack (as explained [here](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql/custom-business-logic/#extend-amplify-generated-resolvers)), the `$ctx.stash.tableName` will be Comment-xxxxx-dev. How can I slot a VTL resolver which has a different data source (*Post* table)

What I tried:
Extending `Mutation.createComment.init.1.req.vtl` resolvers and hardcoding `$util.qr($ctx.stash.defaultValues.put("postCommentsId", "123xyz"))`. It did insert *123xyz* as the value of `postCommentsId`